# Почему гит не меняет файлы при переключении ветки?

Tags: git, github, git-checkout

Есть один проект с 2мя ветками. В первой уже готовая первая версия программы, во второй ветке наброски новой версии. Очень долго не заходил в этот проект и после этого перестали появляться файлы при переключении на первую ветку. Хотя все изменения с GitHub качал, и всё работало. Заново сделать pull этой ветки не даёт, т.к. ветка уже обновлена.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с этим -_-

```
┌──(dgdays㉿DGDays)-[~/mini_library_2020]
└─$ git checkout school_lite
Переключено на ветку «school_lite»
                                                                                
┌──(dgdays㉿DGDays)-[~/mini_library_2020]
└─$ git fetch --all         
Извлечение из origin
Username for 'https://github.com': DgDays
Password for 'https://DgDays@github.com': 
                                                                                
┌──(dgdays㉿DGDays)-[~/mini_library_2020]
└─$ git pull origin school_lite
подсказка: Pulling without specifying how to reconcile divergent branches is
подсказка: discouraged. You can squelch this message by running one of the following
подсказка: commands sometime before your next pull:
подсказка: 
подсказка:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge (the default strategy)
подсказка:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
подсказка:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
подсказка: 
подсказка: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
подсказка: preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
подсказка: or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
подсказка: invocation.
Username for 'https://github.com': DgDays
Password for 'https://DgDays@github.com': 
Из https://github.com/DgDays/mini_library_2020
 * branch            school_lite -> FETCH_HEAD
Уже обновлено.
                                                                                
┌──(dgdays㉿DGDays)-[~/mini_library_2020]
└─$ git status                 
На ветке school_lite
Неотслеживаемые файлы:
  (используйте «git add <файл>…», чтобы добавить в то, что будет включено в коммит)
    "\320\232\320\273\320\270\320\265\320\275\321\202 \320\261\320\270\320\261\320\273\320\270\320\276\321\202\320\265\320\272\320\260\321\200\321\214/node_modules/"
    "\320\232\320\273\320\270\320\265\320\275\321\202 \321\207\320\270\321\202\320\260\321\202\320\265\320\273\321\214(\320\237\320\232 \320\277\320\276\320\272\320\260 XD)/"

ничего не добавлено в коммит, но есть неотслеживаемые файлы (используйте «git add», чтобы отслеживать их)
                                                                                
┌──(dgdays㉿DGDays)-[~/mini_library_2020]
└─$ ls                           
 Server  'Клиент библиотекарь'  'Клиент читатель'
```

В последнем статусе видно, что есть папка `node_modules`, хотя в первая версия - чистый `python`

Comment: Для начала - надо забрать изменения по веткам с сервера на локальный компьютер (гит).
```git fetch --all``` После этого делаете чекаут.

Comment: @AndrewHolovko, сделал. Но ничего не поменялось -_-

Comment: не может такого быть) Давайте полностью команды, которые вы выполняете, последовательно.

Comment: @AndrewHolovko, добавил